# How to calculate secondary diagonals mean in a 2D array?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I want to calculate the mean of each secondary diagonal in the NumPy array. For example, I have this array :

```
    b=np.array([[1,3,4,2],[6,3,5,1],[7,8,9,12],[5,6,9,3],[8,7,3,2],[4,5,6,9]])
```

and I want to write a code that the output would be:

```
    np.array([1, 4.5, 4.6, 5, 6, 8, 3.6, 4, 9])
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There's only one secondary diagonal. What do you mean you want "each secondary diagonal"? Please explain how you arrive at your expected output.

Comment: I think the intent is to average the "anti-diagonals", i.e. the diagonals that run from the top right to the bottom left.

Comment: yes Warren Wechesser that's exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
In [47]: b
Out[47]: 
array([[ 1,  3,  4,  2],
       [ 6,  3,  5,  1],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 12],
       [ 5,  6,  9,  3],
       [ 8,  7,  3,  2],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  9]])

In [48]: nr, nc = b.shape
```

Reverse `b` so the diagonals of `rb` are the anti-diagonals of `b`:

```
In [49]: rb = b[::-1]
```

Compute the means of the diagonals of `rb`:

```
In [50]: np.array([np.diagonal(rb, k).mean() for k in range(1 - nr, nc)])
Out[50]:
array([1.        , 4.5       , 4.66666667, 5.        , 6.        ,
       8.        , 3.66666667, 4.        , 9.        ])
```